# NHibernate projection: How to get a typed type using the Criteria API with projection

Tags: nhibernate, projection, criteria-api

```
 List<object[]> products = GetSession().CreateCriteria<Product>()
            .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                               .Add(Projections.Property("Id"))
                               .Add(Projections.Property("Name"))
                               .Add(Projections.Property("Price"))
             )
             .List();
```

> ```
> public class ProductRow
> {
>      public int Id { get; set; }
>      public string Name { get; set; }
>      public double Price { get; set; }
> }
> ```

How can I get the result as a List<ProductRow> type?

I see there is a function Projection.Cast, but I don't see any documentation on how to use it.

Comment: porjection --> projection
Ceritria --> Criteria

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try setting a result transformer:

```
var result = GetSession()
    .CreateCriteria<Product>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Property("Id"), "Id")
        .Add(Projections.Property("Name"), "Name")
        .Add(Projections.Property("Price"), "Price")
    )
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<ProductRow>())
    .List<ProductRow>();
```

Note the usage of alias pointing to a property name of a `ProductRow` when adding each projection.

Comment: `.Add(Projections.Property("Category.Name"), "Category")` in this case I getting error: 'could not resolve property: Category.Name of Project.Domain.Model.Product'.

Comment: I believe you need to add an alias for your Category property and use the alias name instead. So if you'd use AddAlias to give "Category" an alias of "c", you'd use "c.Name" instead of "Category.Name".